# Dynamically register custom ActionFilter on ActionMethod with shared name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, nopcommerce

I'm building a NopCommerce plugin and want to register a custom ActionFilter with a FilterProvider on an ActionMethod that has shared ActionName with other methods.

Here are two of the ActionMethods with same ActionName

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[FormValueRequired("cancelorder")]      
public ActionResult CancelOrder(int id)
{...}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[FormValueRequired("captureorder")]      
public ActionResult CaptureOrder(int id)
{...}
```

In my filter provider I somehow need to separate the CancelOrder method from CaptureOrder:

```
public class OrderFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IActionFilter _actionFilter;

    public OrderFilterProvider(IActionFilter actionFilter)
    {
        _actionFilter = actionFilter;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {       
        if (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(OrderController) &&
            actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("Edit"))
        {
            return new Filter[] 
            { 
                new Filter(_actionFilter, FilterScope.Action, null)
            };
        }

        return new Filter[] { };
    }
}
```

With this code the filter gets registered on both CancelOrder and CaptureOrder, how can I register it only on the CancelOrder method?

My idea was to separate them based on method name or the parameter value in the FormValueRequired attribute but no luck in finding a way of doing that.

FormValueRequired doesnt have any public properties and looks like:

```
public class FormValueRequiredAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute {
private readonly string[] _submitButtonNames;
private readonly FormValueRequirement _requirement;

public FormValueRequiredAttribute(params string[] submitButtonNames):
    this(FormValueRequirement.Equal, submitButtonNames)
{
}

public FormValueRequiredAttribute(FormValueRequirement requirement, params string[] submitButtonNames)
{
    //at least one submit button should be found
    this._submitButtonNames = submitButtonNames;
    this._requirement = requirement;
}
}
```

And here is what it looks like in my debugger: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=4843369

Is there no way to get the name of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I can see between those 2 actions is the presence of some custom `FormValueRequired` attribute which unfortunately you haven't shown nor explain what it does, but I guess it is some action selector. Anyway, you could retrieve this attribute:

```
public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
{
    if (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(OrderController) &&
        actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("Edit"))
    {
        // Get the FormValueRequiredAttribute that was used to decorate the action
        var formValueRequiredAttribute = actionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FormValueRequiredAttribute), false)
            .Cast<FormValueRequiredAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        // if the action was decorated with this attribute we could read the
        // property that was passed to the constructor (hopefully it is exposed
        // as a public property)
        if (formValueRequiredAttribute != null && 
            formValueRequiredAttribute.SomeParameter == "captureorder")
        {
            // The CaptureOrder action was invoked
            return new Filter[] 
            { 
                new Filter(_actionFilter, FilterScope.Action, null)
            };
        }
    }

    return new Filter[] { };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Darin, unfortunately the property is not exposed as public. I added code and debugger image to my post.

Comment: Then I am afraid that you have no ways of distinguishing between the 2 actions. Go ahead and modify the attribute and expose the value as a public property. As an alternative you could read the value from the `HttpContext` but this might lead to repetition of code between your custom `FormValueRequiredAttribute` and the `OrderFilterProvider`.

Comment: That would work. But since this is for a plugin I don't want to modify the core code. I guess I will have to look into other ways of doing this.

Comment: The other way is to read the value from the request that you could retrieve from the `controllerContext` variable.

Comment: What value from the controllerContext can help me distinguishing between the 2 actions?

Comment: The submit button that was clicked. Look at the `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["name_of_your_submit_button"]` where you should replace the `name_of_your_submit_button` key with the correct value. If you do not know it you could inspect the `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params` value in your debugger and look for the correct key which would give you either `captureorder` or `cancelorder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darin, that solved it. And here is the line of code that did the trick: 

controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Params.AllKeys[0] == "cancelorder"

Answer (score 1):

The FormValueRequired attribute actually checks the 'name' of the posted data. So if your POSTed form has a name-value-pair with name 'cancelorder', the Action method will be executed. (Interestingly enough, FormValueRequired checks on the 'name' of the name-value-pair', but not the 'value' of the name-value-pair').

In other words, keep your ActionFilter, and let both the Action fire the ActionFilter. But in your actual ActionFilter method, check if the POSTed form has the appropriate name, with the code:

```
controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["cancelorder"];
```

You can easily get the ControllerContext in your OnXXX ActionFilter method parameter. :)

Comment: You can have a deeper look at 'Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers.FormValueRequiredAttribute' to examine exactly how this attribute is written. :)

Comment: why it is used ? is it for security purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to notice: even though the FormValueRequired attribute only checks the 'name' of the posted data, you will still need to provide a value for it to work.

For example, this will not work:

```
<input type="submit" name="continueshopping" value="" class="continue-shopping-button" />
```

I wanted a button with no text value, so I had to enter a blank space for the value, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="continueshopping" value=" " class="continue-shopping-button" />
```